# python , mac - Storing a string inside "command v"

Tags: python, macos

I have a very simple script in python which generates a sentence.
For simplicity let's say I have :

```
var = "hello world"
```

I want to be able to paste (<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>) the string, directly after running
the script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call the `pbcopy` command from within your script. For example:

```
from subprocess import call
var = "Hello world!"
cmd = 'echo "%s" | pbcopy' % var
call([cmd], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use NSPasteboard from AppKit

```
def sendToClipBoard(string):
    from AppKit import NSPasteboard,NSObject,NSStringPboardType
    pasteboard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    emptyOwner = NSObject.alloc().init()
    pasteboard.declareTypes_owner_([NSStringPboardType], emptyOwner)
    pasteboard.setString_forType_(string, NSStringPboardType)
```

Code copied from [Notestoself](http://lnotestoself.blogspot.be/2010/04/send-text-to-mac-clipboard-from-python.html)